# Printing and filling a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, random, 2d, multidimensional-array

ORIGINAL POST:
Okay, so this is an exercise I worked through and understand how it works quite well, however I have an assignment where I have to fill an array with random numbers and then have it print out, as well as be able to search the array for a particular number (query) and print the number in inputted location.
The array needs to be 5 rows, 10 columns, so I know that in my definitions I need to change the 4 and 5 accordingly. However, I am not sure how to generate a random number per place in the array. I know the following has to be used somewhere, but I'm not quite sure how or where in the code it should be. I also have to use functions...and generate a menu for the user to choose actions from, one for fill, print, query, and terminate. I obviously need to replace the locations within the array with a variable in order to make the locations dependent on the random number generator while still making sure they're random and not all the same. (0-999)

EDITED POST:

Okay, so I have now been able to get the array to fill and store random numbers, I need to adjust the values accordingly to have them match the dimensions of the array and the range, but it's a start. However, I need to now create a menu that I can prompt the user to enter a character and perform a task such as:

> MENU
>
> Select one of the following options:
>
> F. Fill the array with a random number series.
>
> P. Print the array.
>
> Q. Query the array.
>
> Z. Terminate the program.

and ultimately an 'M' to recall the menu

SOME PARAMETERS:

-- The fill option will fill an array of 50 integers
with
random numbers in the range
1...999.

**Each time the fill option is executed, it will fill the array with a new
random number series.

-- Print the array will print the numbers to the screen.

-- Query will ask the user to enter a location (index), and will then print the number
in that location. If the user enters an invalid location, it will print a message
stating so.

EDITED CODE:

```
/* Generate a random number permutation.*/

 #include < stdio.h >

 #include < stdlib.h >

 #define ARY_SIZE 20

//Function Declarations

void bldPerm (int randomNos[]);

void printData (int data[], int size, int lineSize);

int main(void)

{

//Local Declarations

    int randNos[ARY_SIZE];

//Statements

    printf("Begin Random Numbers Permutation Generation\n");

    bldPerm (randNos);

    printData (randNos, ARY_SIZE, 10);

    return 0;
}//main

/*=====================bldPerm======================*/


void bldPerm(int randNos[])

{

//LD's

    int oneRandNo;

    int haveRand[ARY_SIZE] = { 0 };


//Statements

    for (int i = 0; i < ARY_SIZE; i++)

        {

        do

            {
            oneRandNo = rand() % ARY_SIZE;

        } while (haveRand[oneRandNo] == 1);

        haveRand[oneRandNo] = 1;

        randNos[i] = oneRandNo;

    } //for

    return;

}//bldPerm

/*=====================printData======================*/

void  printData(int data[], int size, int lineSize)

{

//LD's

    int numPrinted = 0;

//Statements

    printf(" \n ");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)

        {

        numPrinted++;

        printf(" %2d ", data[i]);

        if (numPrinted >= lineSize)

            {

            printf(" \n ");

            numPrinted = 0;

            }//if

        }//for

    printf(" \n ");

    return;

}//printData
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. It sounds like you're asking: how to generate random numbers and populate the array with them and how to break a single main function into several smaller functions. These are pretty basic tasks, did you do any research or make an attempt at either of them?

Comment: I posted some edited code as to what I have right now with what is expected as well, hopefully that will clarify things. Thanks.

Comment: @th3doorMATT If you can fill the array, you can both search through and print the entire array. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the wrong forum for this kind of questions but anyway.

First try:

1) Remove the initialization of the quizScores
2) Initialize the seed using srand(time(NULL)); Remember to include time.h
2) Make a double for loop for initializing the elements using rand()%100. This will give random numbers between 0 and 100.

With the menu, I would suggest using a while look and query for actions using getchar()

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple start to all of your array issues. The menu you have to implement should deal with a switch statement and then its corresponding function call.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool searchArray(int *A, int m, int n, int key){
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if ( (*((A+i*n)+j)) == key )
                return true;
    return false;
}

void printArray(int *A, int m, int n){
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("(%d) ", *((A+i*n)+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void fillArray(int *A, int m, int n){
    int i, j;
    time_t t;
    srand(time(&t));

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            *((A+i*n)+j) = rand() % 100;
}

int main(){
    int m = 5, n = 10, key = 10, A[m][n];
    bool found = false;

    fillArray((int *)A, m, n);
    printArray((int *)A, m, n);
    found = searchArray((int *)A, m, n, key);

    if ( found == true ){
        printf("%d was in the array!\n", key);
    } else {
        printf("%d was not in the array!\n", key);
    }

    return 0;
}
```